# How to create values list with KnexJS

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I want to generate a dynamic table to be used in a query. To do this I want to use PostgreSQL VALUES list feature documented here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-values.html

The SQL would look something like this:

```
with my_values (id, "name") as (
    values (1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three')
)
select *
from my_values mv
join some_other_table sot
    on sot.value_id = mv.id
```

I can't find anything in the KnexJS documentation that supports generating the above SQL besides just using `raw` for the whole query which kind of defeats the point of using KnexJS.

**Is there a way to create a values list for a part of the query in KnexJS?**

Comment: `knex` is a sql query builder, therefore, it doesn't support a DB specific syntax like `with`.

Comment: @felixmosh it actually does support `with` (http://knexjs.org/#Builder-with). The specific thing I am trying to figure out is the value list. I'd even be ok if there was a way to add a partial raw statement to a larger constructed one if that was possible.

Answer (score 3):

In order to construct the following query

```sql
with my_values as (
    Select *
    from (values(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three')) as inner (id, name)
)
select *
from my_values mv
join some_other_table as sot on sot.value_id = mv.id
```

The problem is that `knex` doesn't supports column list definition as you've written.
Postgress, supports this

```sql
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three')) AS t (num,letter);
```

So, the query above can be built like:

```
const vals = [
  { id: 1, name: 'one' },
  { id: 2, name: 'two' },
  { id: 3, name: 'three' },
];

const params = vals.reduce((result, { id, name }) => result.concat(id, name), []);


await db
  .with(
    `my_values`,
    db.raw(
      `Select * from (values ${vals.map(() => `(?, ?)`).join(',')}) as inner (id, name)`,
      params
    )
  )
  .select('*')
  .from('my_values mv')
  .join('some_other_table', 'some_other_table.value_id', 'mv.id');
```

It's generates

```js
{
  bindings: [ 1, 'one', 2, 'two', 3, 'three' ],
  sql: 'with `my_values` as (Select * from (values (?, ?),(?, ?),(?, ?)) as inner (id, name)) select * from `my_values_mv` inner join `some_other_table` on `some_other_table`.`value_id` = `mv`.`id`'
}
```